# Select box creation in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-select

I have created one dynamic select box using jquery mobile android application.It was created good, but when i am going to next list view page and get back to the same select box page.The select box is disappear.The page is displaying as blank. For your reference i have attached my select box creation code here.Anything i missed in this.
Please tell me the answer.
Thanks in advance.

```
function candidate(id)
{   
window.localStorage.setItem("ojtid",id);    
$('#cadidateid').find('option').remove();
var content='';     
db.transaction(function (tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('select * from xxx where xxid="'+id+'" and status="1"', [], function (tx, result)
    {

        if(result.rows.length > 0)
        {
            alert("This is already attended");              
        }
        else
        {           

            tx.executeSql('SELECT distinct emp_id,emp_name FROM yyy where yyid="'+id+'" group by emp_id ORDER BY emp_name ASC', [], function (tx, results)
            {                               

                content=content+"<option value='0'>-- Select --</option>";
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
                {
                    content=content+'<option value="'+results.rows.item(i).emp_id+'">'+results.rows.item(i).emp_name+'</option>';
                }                                   

                console.log("content:"+content);                    

                $("#cadidateid").append(content).trigger('create');
                $('#cadidateid').selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);

            });     
        }
        $.mobile.changePage($("#ojtcandidate"));
    });
});

}

Html Code:

<div data-role="page" id="ojtcandidate" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Ojt Candidate</h1>
        </div>

         <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <label for="day">Select Candidate</label>
            <form>
                <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">                     

                    <select name="cadidateid" id="cadidateid" data-native-menu="false">

                    </select> 

                </fieldset>

            </form> 
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="session();">
        </div> 
    </div>
```